# ASP.NET - ConstraintException was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

Been dabbling with a bit of ASP.NET. I current have the following error:
`Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints`

It breaks on the following line:
 `DataTable propertyTable = pta.searchByType(sType);`

Code:

```
String sType = Request.QueryString["type"];
DataSetTableAdapters.propertiesTableAdapter pta = new DataSetTableAdapters.propertiesTableAdapter();
DataTable propertyTable = pta.searchByType(sType);
if (propertyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Your Results";
    gvProperty.DataSource = propertyTable;
    gvProperty.DataBind();
}
```

The query that `pta.searchByType(sType);` is calling is:

```
SELECT     property_id, name, description, price, image, town
FROM         properties
WHERE     (date_approved IS NOT NULL) AND (property_type = @property_type)
```

The primary key for the properties table is `property_id`, the table has one FK that links to a users table but that's it.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is great. If you need any more details just drop them in the comments below.

Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with asp.net.

Comment: Why doesn't it? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build an asp.net website. This is a problem I have in one of my .cs files. If there is a more specific tag, feel free to edit it.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint to the line where the exception is thrown. Then you can call the failing line in the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28VS.80%29.aspx) and then call `propertyTable.GetErrors()` there. Now you see all rows of the DataTable that have errors with the exact, original reason.

Comment: @Tim - Great little tip, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you selecting ALL the columns?

See:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1400495.aspx/1

You can always cheat and set enable constraints to false on the table adapter, too.